# Python Configparser not reading file. Says file is not existing

Tags: python

I have project structure is like

```
Root
  |--config
       |---settings.cfg

  |--utilities
       |---ConfigReader.py
```

**ConfigReader.py**

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

try:
    with open('./config/settings.cfg') as f:
        config.readfp(f)
except IOError as e:
    raise Exception('Error reading settings.cfg file. '+format(str(e)))
```

When run above ConfigReader.py, I get always;

```
    raise Exception('Error reading settings.cfg file. '+format(str(e)))
Exception: Error reading settings.cfg file. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './config/settings.cfg'
```

I changed providing filepath with back slash/front slash and dots.None working to me.

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you running the file from?

Comment: @DroidX86 Im running it in the PyCharm . My oS is MAC OSX

Comment: I meant which directory

Comment: @DroidX86in the pycharm console I have virtual env, where I run like /Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/testpython/utilities/ConfigReader.py

Comment: In the configuration for that run, you'll have a "working directory". It's usually set to the project directory. Look for "Edit configurations"

Comment: @DroidX86Working directory is set as /Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/testpython/utilities

Comment: That's the issue. The path you have in your code will resolve to: `/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/testpython/utilities/config/settings.cfg` - which obviously doesn't exist. Set the working directory to `/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/testpython/` and try again

Answer (score 0):

read like this, also make sure that the file is in path.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('./config/settings.cfg')
```

Comment: It is not working, so I moved to try block to capture the exception

Comment: try with 'settings.cfg' in the utilities folder itself. config.read('.settings.cfg')